# Вычитания из массива php

Tags: php

Есть массив такого вида

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
         (
            [id] => 706
            [vendor_code] => 1006-0604
            [manufacturer] => 
            [quantitys] => 14
            [name_invoice] => № 274 04/01/2018
            [oll_quantity] => 0
            [data_creation] => 2018-01-04 16:26:33
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 823
            [vendor_code] => 1006-0604
            [manufacturer] => 
            [quantitys] => 1
            [name_invoice] => № 296 09/01/2018
            [oll_quantity] => 42
            [data_creation] => 2018-01-09 12:38:25
        )
)
```

В процессии добавления станет больше, как сделать что бы отнималось сначала от первого  `[quantitys] => 14` до тех пор пока не будет  = 0 , а потом с второго и тд

Answer (score 0):

Пробегаем по всем элементам, проверяем значение поля, если больше или равно 14, то отнимаем по единице до тех пор, пока не станет равно 0, это имелось в виду?

```
foreach($array as &$item) {
   while($item['quantitys'] != 0) {
      $item['quantitys']--;
   }
}
```

Если просто обнулить надо эти поля, то можно так сделать

```
foreach($array as &$item) {
    $item['quantitys'] -= $item['quantitys'];
}
```

или

```
foreach($array as &$item) {
    $item['quantitys'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего имелось просто вычитание, без привязки к числу 14

Comment: `[quantities] => 14`  это скопированная строка дампа массива, а не условие

Comment: Ок, тогда еще проще все)